# hibernate search - search phrase in any order

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

Hi have the following search phrase

2012 nissan gtr black

Im trying to create a keyword search that will return that index with a key phrase being entered in any order.

Example

"Black gtr" or "2012 gtr black" etc.

Im using the following suggestion guide, but can't seem to figure out how to get the the search to search the index in any order. I tried keyword, but that seemed to return other indexs.

```
Query query = title.phrase().withSlop(2)
             .onField (TITLE_NGRAM_INDEX)
             .andField(TITLE_EDGE_NGRAM_INDEX).boostedTo(5)
             .sentence(searchTerm.toLowerCase()).createQuery();

FullTextQuery fullTextQuery = getFullTextSession()
.createFullTextQuery(query, Product.class);   

fullTextQuery.setMaxResults(20);
```

http://n-chandra.blogspot.com/2013/09/hibernate-search-based-autocomplete.html?m=1

Anybody know how to get this to work?

Comment: Phase search is not working in this case. You want indeed to do a keyword search. I think instead of asking so many related questions you should havea closer look the Hibernate Serch and Lucene documentation. In particular what analysers do and why and how you use it. They break you text into words and make the separate words searchable. Also have a look at all the different query types, keyword vs phrase etc. Lucene's query parser syntax documentation is also a good read. You will ned to understand these concepts to write the right queries.

Comment: @Hardy, I've read the documentation, but when you are completely unfamiliar with the project, sometimes it's still very difficult to understand. Don't get me wrong, I think you guys did a great job creating the documentation, but in some places it's still not very clear. I started off using keywords, but I found it to just add other non relevant index's to my search rather than filter the search. Example, If I searched Nissan Black, it would return Nissan Black, but also Ford Black. So if I use keyword, how do I get it to filter on my search terms, please feel free to point me to the docs.